# Metricbeat Jolokia jmx mapping

Tags: jolokia, metricbeat

I am currently experimenting with Metricbeat with Jolokia using ELK 7.2.0 using docker-compose, and I was able to get JMX metrics to display in Kibana.

My issue is that I need to ***configure per JMX metric the mapping*** in the jmx.mappings section of the metricbeat configuration YML the metrics that I would like to have send to ELK.

Question is it possible to pass some sort of wildcard configuration so that metricbeat ***simply pulls all the jmx metrics and sends it to ELK*** ?

Thank you, kindly
  Luis Oscar Trigueiros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to wait for https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/8168, which will hopefully make some progress soon.